# Synchronize LDAP with Salesforce

Tags: community

Am trying to synchronize LDAP with salesforce. Is there any way or any software available to do this? Identity connect is used for sync AD with salesforce but I did not get anything for LDAP synchronization.

Comment: SF product team has been working on adding LDAP support to Identity Connect. You should contact your SF account team for the latest info.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should search for SSO instead of synchronise the LDAP.

If you have a LDAP, you probably have a Active directory and hence you are able to implement Federate authentication again your LDAP.

> Since its release in 2005, the Security Assertion Markup Language
>   (better known as SAML) version 2.0 has established itself as the
>   dominant standard for cross-domain web single sign-on in the
>   enterprise space, with salesforce.com introducing support in the
>   Winter '09 release (October 2008) and Microsoft in Active Directory
>   Federation Services (AD FS) version 2.0 in May 2010.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services) you have a complete sample of how to configure your AD FS for LDAP

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it's incorrect in the context of the question. SSO via SAML still requires a user account to exist on SF side. While Just-in-time provisioning is available as a feature in SF's implementation of SAML, the number of restrictions on just-in-time provisioning versus the firepower of Identity Connect make these two options be like apples and oranges.